# Jquery UI Tabs Link instead of tabcontainer

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

I have problem with one of my php projects where I am using jquery ui Tabs

I will try to explain it as simple as possible:

I need to make the tablink

```
<ul><li><a href="test.php"></a></li></ul>
```

to call the test.php in a complete new page. Not only loaded as tabcontent as usually.

Can anybody give me a hint please.

Comment: How will you know if you want to load the tab or load the new page?

Comment: It actually loads the php page but the problem ist that its a Controller(Mvc Pattern) which has to recieve $Get Parameter. And this is not working.  So i just want to use the tabs as a simple menu with links to click...

Comment: Just to clarify, when you click a tab you want a new page to be rendered? Does this mean load a completely new page or load div with a new page?

Comment: Yes.. It has to load a complete new page..  I see no other solution..   for 1 Tab entry of the ul list i just want to open the link..

Comment: Then just set your parameters: `href="test.php?whatever=1&other=that"`?

Comment: In jQuery you can set an id to that tab, then have $(document).on('click', '#tabId', function(){ window.location.href='www.google.com' }); This would act like you were clicking a link when clicking on your tab assuming your tab's id was tabId

Comment: I suppose the other option is to style links like tabs, this way you have your styling without the added functionality of tabs that you aren't actually using.

Comment: the $(document).on ... isnt working.. nothing is happening.

Comment: The $(document).on is binding an event to the id of the tab for when it is clicked it then activates that function.

Answer (score 0):

In jQuery you can set an id to that tab, then have

```
<script>    
  $(document).on('click', '#tabId', function(){ 
    window.location.href='www.google.com'; 
  }); 
</script>
```

This would act like you were clicking a link when clicking on your tab assuming your tab's id was tabId.

It sounds like you want links that look like tabs. The other solution that I can see is actually stylizing links to look like tabs using CSS.

Comment: i tried this and the $('#id').click event but its not working.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/FERMIS/EeHmL/ This has the jQuery tabs copied from http://jqueryui.com/tabs/ and I have an added id to the first tab, when clicked it should have a pop up box. If you replace that js alert code with window.location.href='example.com'; it should redirect the page. It might not work in the jsfiddle because they are structured a little wierd.

Comment: I only added the js and changed <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li> to have an id as test which looks like the following <li><a id='test' href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>

Comment: Thx i solved it a bit different and it works.  i'm setting onclick event to the a tag and call a js function which loads a new window...  i feel bad for such a stupid code but it works :)   thank you so much